# maven jetty plugin - remove localhost/server name from url

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-8

i am running my web application using maven jetty plugin.
I can access my web application either through `localhost`, `ip` or `server name`.

*But let say i want to access my application using application name.*

eg.

```
http://ip:port/login/login.jsp
http://servername:port/login/login.jsp
```

**I want it something like, no port or ip.**

```
http://applicationname/login/login.jsp
```

**pom.xml**

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
                <configuration>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                            <port>port</port>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <stopPort>18080</stopPort>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webXml>target/classes/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <!-- <webApp> <contextPath>/</contextPath> </webApp> -->

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done using maven-jetty-plugin or other. Jetty is a servlet container which is running in a operating system and listening on a specified port for http requests. This cannot be changed.

However to achieve what you need you can modify hosts  file (linux: `/etc/hosts`; windows: `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file).

Your hosts configuration could like like: 
`127.0.0.1 applicationname`

Keep in mind that you cannot define the port name. Also keep in mind that this is not your application configuration but configuration of host where you're hosting your app.

Comment: But what about the parameter inside `connector`, `<port>port</port>`, whatever port i define here it listen to it.

Comment: Yes. I meant that you cannot define the port in the hosts file.