# Jetty: Hide port number in the URL

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I buy a domain name: `test.com`.

Then I run jetty by doing:

```
/opt/jetty# nohup java -jar start.jar
```

When I go on my web site (`http://test.com`), It's not working, I need to add the port number like: `http://test.com:8080` and this is very dirty. So, I want to delete or hide this port number.

What I tried is to run jetty with the port number like:

```
nohup java -jar start.jar -Djetty.http.port=8080
```

Then, in the file jetty-http.xml (in `/opt/jetty/etc`), I changed the line:

```
<Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="8080" /></Set>
```

I am using:

- Vaadin.
- Maven.
- Jetty.

Where should I manage this?

**EDIT :**

As required, this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>8.0.4</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.0.4</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jetty.port>8080</jetty.port>
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>/login</contextPath>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

To prevent question, I tried to delete the 
`<jetty.port>8080</jetty.port>` without sucess.

**EDIT** : Based on [maven jetty plugin - remove localhost/server name from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693480/maven-jetty-plugin-remove-localhost-server-name-from-url)

I tried to changed the `localhost`to myapplicationname from `/etc/hosts`. I restart jetty. And, it's not working

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to use the 80 port as the Jetty's one (`jetty.http.port`), because `http://test.com/` means that the port is the default — 80.

Additional references:

1. [networking - Why was port 80 chosen as the default HTTP port and 443 as the default HTTPS port? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/996828/).
2. [java - Change Jetty default port - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644114/).

## Update

This sentence clarifies the problem a little bit:

> I'm sorry, I don't know how I can provide more.. I installed Jetty 9 on a debian
>
> — Bob, [the original message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40083805#40083805).

Edit the `/etc/default/jetty9` file as follows:

```
# Additional arguments to pass to Jetty
JETTY_ARGS=jetty.port=80

# If you run Jetty on port numbers that are all higher than 1023, then you
# do not need authbind. It is used for binding Jetty to lower port numbers.
# (yes/no, default: no)
AUTHBIND=yes
```

Then, restart the Jetty server:

```
# service jetty9 restart
```

Comment: This is was I tried and describe in the post. This is not deleting the :8080 in the URL.

Comment: @Bob, could you please update the question by adding [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the content of the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: I added the pom.xml.

Comment: I don't think it's in my java code... and my code contain huge lines. I think it's in maven or jetty configuration

Comment: @Bob, it would be great, if you could provide a minimal, but complete example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159262/discussion-between-bob-and-sergey-brunov).

Comment: @Bob, please see the updated answer (after having the first chat).

Comment: I tried your solutions, both are not working. In the first one, I cannot find the logs error...And it seems to be a solution to run projet on port 80. My project is working but I want to hide the :8080 from the URL

Comment: @Bob, let's get back to the chat.